# Does a ColumnDataSource change the row order when deriving from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, bokeh

I was hoping to rely on the order of the dataframe to sort by group size of various clusters of data such that the most populous levels of a classification appear early in the data frame and small rare populations appear at the end. The goal I'm pursuing is to ensure that my rare populations always appear on top in the z-order of my scatter plot.

I experimented with a simple example of stacked circles and discovered that the z-order is not what I expected by their arrangement in the original dataframe I defined them as.

Here's a minimal example to demonstrate with

```
import pandas
import numpy
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server

def modify_doc(doc):
    df = pandas.DataFrame()

    theta = numpy.linspace( 0 , 2*numpy.pi , 20 )
    colors = ['yellow' if (c % 2 == 0) else 'blue' for c in range(len(theta))]

    df['X'] = numpy.cos(theta)
    df['Y'] = numpy.sin(theta)

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df) # does this change the order?

    plot = figure()
    plot.circle('X', 'Y', source=source, radius=0.22 , fill_alpha=1, color=colors)

    plot.add_tools( HoverTool( tooltips=[ ( '(x,y)', '$x,$y') , ( 'index' , "$index" ) ] ) )
    doc.add_root(plot)


bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

# Setting num_procs here means we can't touch the IOLoop before now, we must
# let Server handle that. If you need to explicitly handle IOLoops then you
# will need to use the lower level BaseServer class.
server = Server({'/': bokeh_app})
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

I'm finding two things confusing here, I expect the order to run counterclockwise with the discs in the first quadrant all beneath the subsequent disc. Instead I see discs on the top with the subsequent disc on the bottom. Such rendering would be consistent with a reverse plotting given that the last data point in the dataframe was plotting first all the way to the first data point. However I see other inconsistencies with the two discs which are eclipsed by two discs, something that I can't explain at all apart from wondering if a `ColumnDataSource` rearranges my data so the renderer obeys the order in the rearranged `ColumnDataSource` and not my original `DataFrame`. Is this accurate? How does Bokeh settle on a z-order with respect to a DataFrame's row order, is there any predictable relationship between the two?

[image: overlaid circles demonstrating confusing z-order]

The real problem about the clustering is that we have a full event record with several hundred thousand data points. The algorithms subsample the data to classify with, and then I take that subsample classifications and conditionally color data points by those labels. The bulk of the data is unsampled and I'd like it to essentially play to the background. Both sampled and unsampled data are in the same `ColumnDataSource` which is convenient instead of plotting  two distinct glyphs which I may consider to force a z-order. In this scatter plot below, gray data points represent unsampled data.
[image: dense scatter plot with unknown z-order behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColumnDataSource` does not ever change the order of the data. However in order to optimize drawing and hit-testing, points are copied from teh CDN and put into a [spatial index](https://github.com/mourner/rbush) by the glyph views. The order that points are returned when the index is queried is not specified, which explains the result you are seeing.

It's possible that an option could be added to disable spatial indexing (at least for drawing, it will aways be necessary to make hit-testing performant on non-trivial datasets), but this would require new development, so a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to request the feature would be the next step. It should not be a hard task, but the core team is overextended, so if you have the ability to collaborate and become a contributor that would be the quickest path to getting it added.

All that said, if you are needing to display hundreds of thousands of points, you may want to have a look at [DataShader](https://datashader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a fast, configurable rendering pipeline for larger data sets that integrates closely with Bokeh. (It has been demonstrated interactively exploring hundreds of millions of points on a laptop on many occasions)

Comment: aha so that explains it, a performant data structure tradeoff for the differentiating features (interactivity being a huge one) of going the Bokeh route. I tried playing with data partitioning and subsequent glyph constructions to force a z-order, didn't seem to change the plot but I only tested a single data set. I'll check out DataShader, thanks for the good tip.

Comment: I do think an option to toggle the use of the spatial index for drawing would be reasonable and fairly simple so please do consider making a GH issue for it.